# Удаление устаревших строк в таблице базы Mysql

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Здравствуйте! У меня возникла необходимость в начале работы скрипта PHP удалять из таблицы базы Mysql строки, с момента записи которых в базу прошло более 24 часов. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой задачей, или в Mysql есть для этого какая-то функция? Подскажите, пожалуйста, заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эмм... Точно не знаю, но, по-моему, MySQL сам по себе время записи не запоминает.

Посему поле времени записи добавить и производить удаление всего, где разница времени текущего и записанного больше 24 часов - такой запрос можно сделать без особого труда.

**UPD**:
Пример:

```
DELETE FROM nya WHERE (timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Можно, конечно, написать и по-другому, но смысл примерно тот же самый будет.

Comment: Поле времени есть , время в каждой строке записано. Простите, может где-то есть пример похожего запроса?

Comment: Как-то так, например. \*обновил ответ\*

Comment: DELETE FROM nya WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

Так будет немного нагляднее